# Android Gradle Build Variant to separate manifest files

Tags: android, gradle, admob, android-productflavors

I have a project with structure tree like this:

```
-app
 - src
  -belowgingerbread 
    -class1.java
    -AndroidManifest.xml
  -main
    -class1.java
    -AndroidManifest.xml
```

And my build.gradle is like this:

```
productFlavors {
        belowgingerbread {
            minSdkVersion 7
        }
        abovegingerbread {
            minSdkVersion 9
        }
    }
dependencies {
    abovegingerbreadCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to create two separate activities with AdMob. While belowgingerbread flavor uses the AdView class from old SDK jar to support 2.1 and 2.2, abovegingerbread flavor uses AdView class from play service. But somehow when I'm on belowgingerbreadDebug build Variant, i get an error on default AndroidManifest.xml where it should have compiled the AndroidManifest.xml in belowgingerbread flavor. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I just realised that Manifest files are getting merged. Is there a way to use one of them?

Comment: I don't know if the same rules apply to AndroidManifest.xml, but if you want flavors to use their own version of a file, it should only be found in the flavor source sets. The file should not be in main.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, my problem was with the flavor's package name, it was a typo. But manifest works with manifest merger. So It's a bit different with the class files. Even when you have the manifest file in your flavor package and also in main package, they will get merged according to the tags.